# SSRS 2008 R2 - Group toggle aggregates

Tags: ssrs-2008, toggle, aggregate-functions, ssrs-tablix, ssrs-grouping

I'm working with a dataset where employee utilization is calculated as (Time Billed to X/Standard Billable hours). As such, to get the total billable percentage for an employee, I can just sum up the percentages billed to each client. However, I also want to be able to see the percentage of time billed by department.

I've currently got my data in a matrix with row groups Department-->Employee-->Client with 1 column group of "time sheet ending date". When I toggle the visibility of the client row group based on the employee row group, I get the correct totals at the client and the employee level. However, when I toggle the visibility of the employee row group based on the department row group, the department row group has the wrong totals. For example, if Department A has employee B with 90% utilization and employee C with 95% utilization, the toggled total at the department level is 185%....However, I am expecting to see 92.5%....any ideas????

Answer (score 0):

You might just need to tweak the expression used to get the department total. I am unsure what expression exactly you used, but it should be of the form:

SUM(epmployeePercentageColumn)/COUNT(employeePercentageColumn)

obviously replace the "employeePercentageColumn" with whatever field or variable or expression that represents each of the employee percentages that come under the particular department.

If your current expression isn't in that form, try and tweak it.

Hope it Helps.

Comment: Hi, thanks for you response. Close but no dice. If I implement your above solution, I get the average of the all the individual utilisations in a department. What I really need is a way to get the average of the sum of utlitation by employee.